# Is there an app that's similar to Calendar + Wunderlist?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, calendar

I'm constantly switching between the two, and it's driving me crazy being so disorganized. I use Wunderlist as a to-do list. I'll create a list, titled with the date, and list the things I need to do that day. So every date requires the creation of a list; sometimes I'll have 10-20 lists when I need to plan further ahead, and it gets tricky when I have something coming up weeks or months ahead of time. The issue is, it's hard looking ahead to see what's been planned, what appointments I have, etc. (I know searching is possible, but that's not the same as having an overview of the next few days or weeks).

When I use Apple's Calendar, I essentially do the same thing, each day is a to-do list. But when in month -- the view I find most helpful -- I can't arrange the orders of the items I create. I have to either go to day view or week view and drag it, or set a time, which can be very tedious if done for each item. Week view can also be quite annoying because there's no ability to scroll horizontally (like you would with a webpage or pdf), it jumps week by week, making planning ahead sort of tricky for me. So essentially, I end up creating an unordered list.

Is there an app that can address these issues? I'm aware that there organization / productivity / calendar apps that are loaded with features, but cost a good amount of money. I don't want to be paying for an app of which only 2% of the features are useful to me. So a minimal app, and one that's free or more afforadable -- really, I'd just like to to address the above issues.

I've scoured the internet, but haven't found anything. Please help, I'm pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you the [Clear](http://realmacsoftware.com/clear/) App.
Is a minimal to-do app that allows you to create multiple lists and items within that lists. Furthermore, will allow you to set reminders for every item in your lists.

The app is really minimal which help you keep organised. Another feature of the app is that the higher an item or a list is in your app, then the higher the priority is and therefore the colour (first item is dark red, indicating importance and the last one yellow, indicating not that important).

Is also available for iOS (iPhone, iPad), Apple Watch and Mac OS X, and sync over iCloud to keep everything synchronized.

Is not free though, but for me is my main to-do organiser app for a long time, so for me, worth it's money.